# ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instance-groups.managed.rolling-action.replace) Could not fetch resource

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-build

I am trying to setup healthchecks for vms in instances groups on google cloud, but whenever I try to build the project I got this error.

```
Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instance-groups.managed.rolling-action.replace) Could not fetch resource:
 - Required 'compute.healthChecks.use' permission for 'projects/MY-PROJECT-ID/global/healthChecks/hc'
```

Build complete successfully when I remove healthcheck.

Which permissions should I enable ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accordingly with [Compute Engine roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#compute-engine-roles) you need either:

- `roles/compute.loadBalancerAdmin` or
- `roles/compute.networkAdmin`

Comment: Indeed, adding `Compute Load Balancer Admin` to cloud build service account fixed my issue.

Comment: For reference, [the doc](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/configure-access-for-cloud-build-service-account?authuser=3&_ga=2.161629044.-910988834.1658149378#service-account-permissions-iam-page) explaining how to grant a role to the Cloud Build account.